# How to decompile data segment in ghidra

Tags: ghidra

I have a code in data segment in my bin. Is there a way how to make a ghidra treat some data as a code for decompilation?

Comment: hmm, now sure if I get the question but you can always press <kbd>d</kbd> to turn to disassemble (if the data is is some form - press <kbd>c</kbd> to clear it from any structure)